# Renovate minimumReleaseAge and internalChecksFilter="strict" does not work with group:allNonMajor PR for noise reduction

Tags: renovate

I have a spring boot maven project and using renovate to upgrade dependencies of it.

I had to put in a stability and noise control for PR creation with combination of "minimumReleaseAge": "15 days" and "internalChecksFilter": "strict" as documented in [renovate docs here](https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#minimumreleaseage)

Full configuration:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "extends": [
    "group:recommended"
  ],
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchPackagePatterns": ["*"],
      "allowedVersions": "!/[-.]dev\\.?[0-9]+$/"
    },
    {
      "matchPackagePatterns": ["*"],
      "minimumReleaseAge": "15 days",
      "internalChecksFilter": "strict"
    },
    {
      "matchPackagePatterns": ["*"],
      "excludePackagePatterns": ["^org\\.common\\.libs"],
      "matchUpdateTypes": [
        "minor",
        "patch"
      ],
      "groupName": "all non-major dependencies",
      "groupSlug": "all-minor-patch",
      "minimumReleaseAge": "15 days",
      "internalChecksFilter": "strict"
    },
    {
      "matchPackageNames": ["org.common.libs"],
      "minimumReleaseAge": "0 days"
    }
  ]
}
```

Renovate not creating single PR when minimumReleaseAge doesn't meet. However, renovate is creating the grouped PR's with Pending status even when the property internalChecksFilter is still set to "strict"

Any clue what's wrong or is it supported with grouped PR's